# state space for discrete time PI filter

Tags: control-theory

How to find the state space if I have transfer function below:

$F(z)=[K_0+K_1/(1-z^{-1}) + K_2/(1-z^{-^1})^2 ]$

Thank in advanced

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the canonical forms and their relation to transfer functions.

http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, may i know, it is the canonical forms for continuous time and discrete time is same?